# Augment data frame missed values by another data frame

Tags: r, join, merge

I have following data frames:

```
> df1 = data.frame(ind = 1:4, x=c('a', 'b', NA, 'd'))
> df2 = data.frame(ind = 1:4, x=c(NA, NA, 'c', NA))
> df1
  ind    x
1   1    a
2   2    b
3   3 <NA>
4   4    d
> df2
  ind    x
1   1 <NA>
2   2 <NA>
3   3    c
4   4 <NA>
```

I want combine them filling missing values in df1 by numeric values from df2. How can I do that? I cannot do that neither with merge nor with join commands:

```
> merge(df1, df2, by='ind', all=T)
  ind  x.x  x.y
1   1    a <NA>
2   2    b <NA>
3   3 <NA>    c
4   4    d <NA>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you constructed the test case creates factors and that imposes extra barriers to compact solutions, because the levels are not congruent. You can either create the factors with levels= the union of their unique values or preferably use character vectors:

```
df1 = data.frame(ind = 1:4, x=c('a', 'b', NA, 'd'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 = data.frame(ind = 1:4, x=c(NA, NA, 'c', NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1[is.na(df1)] <- df2[is.na(df1)] # the key is same index on both sides
 df1
#---------
  ind x
1   1 a
2   2 b
3   3 c
4   4 d
```

The arguably less preferred method (but one that might be better for a pair of in place datasets you did not want to reprocess) would be:

```
 df1$x <- factor(df1$x, levels=union(levels(df1$x), levels(df2$x) ) )
 df2$x <- factor(df2$x, levels=union(levels(df1$x), levels(df2$x) ) )
 df1[is.na(df1)] <- df2[is.na(df1)]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good solution. Nevertheless, I experience problems using it: head(a[is.na(a)]) reports non-NA values on my data (too big to be posted here). What may be the cause? May it be caused by a factor in one of the columns?

Comment: Please ignore technical part of the previous message. I resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
rbind(df1[complete.cases(df1),],df2[complete.cases(df2),])
  index x
1     1 a
2     2 b
3     3 c
4     4 d
```

Comment: It will only work if all missed values are located in the end of the second table. My data is more complex so it will not work. I will edit the question now

Comment: @gadubishe My solution still works just fine with your modified example. If you're expecting a specific ordering, you'd simply have to order the data frame after the fact, that's all.

Comment: I get the idea the questioner might not want to drop rows where there are missings in both dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

What do you do if `x` is `NA` in both datasets? Does this do what you want?

```
x <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE, by = "ind")
x <- transform(x, newcol = ifelse(is.na(x.x), as.character(x.y), as.character(x.x)))

> x
  ind  x.x  x.y newcol
1   1    a <NA>      a
2   2    b <NA>      b
3   3 <NA>    c      c
4   4    d <NA>      d
```